# Some help posting to ASP.NET Web API with C#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, asp.net-web-api

I have been playing with ASP.NET Web API. I am looking to see can I post to a method I have built which simply returns back the object I have POSTED:

On The Accounts Controller:

```
// POST /api/accounts
public Account Post(Account account)
{
   return account;

}
```

Code Used To Post:

```
    public void PostAccount()
    {
        // http://local_ip/api/accounts
        var uri = string.Format("{0}", webServiceRoot); 


        var acc = new Account();
        acc.AccountID = "8";
        acc.AccountName = "Mitchel Cars";
        acc.AccountNumber = "600123801";
        acc.SubscriptionKey = "2535-8254-8568-1192";
        acc.ValidUntil = DateTime.Now;


        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        request.ContentLength = 800;

        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Account));
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(request.GetRequestStream(), acc);

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Account));

        var newAcc = (Account)serializer.Deserialize(response.GetResponseStream());

    }
```

I have removed any error checking or any boiler plate code to make it easier to read. This is strictly a spike just to under stand to to actually POST. My understanding is that you should write to the GetRequestStream(). All the reading and such seems to work ok but I never here back from the request.GetResponse();

If I do a simple get it works fine. I did see you can use a class called HTTPClient for doing this stuff but I can't use it as I need to get this working for WinForms, Silverlight and Windows Phone all based on .Net 3.5

Any help pushing POCO's to the server would be a great help, cheers!

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**

- Currently I get no error, the test app just hangs.
- If I turn off the WebAPI project I get a server not found response.
- I have not changed any routes or any of that.
- Gets to the same controller work.

Comment: Nothing, thats the weird part... Not even an unhandled exception, I presume its waiting to time out maybe?

Comment: Also, why are you setting the `ContentLength` property?

Comment: Seems to be, I'm at 4 mins now with the ui for the test app still blocked. I have set the content to 800.

Comment: Oh why am I setting it? I thought you had to set it to a value bigger or equal to the stream

Comment: Nah, let the WebRequest compute that after you have written to the Request stream. The server might just be trying to get X bytes from the stream when they arent there and just hanging in a loop.

Comment: I've removed it but it is still hanging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to close the response stream.  Most examples I see also show setting the content length.  You may be better to serialize to a memory stream and then use the length of that stream as the Content-Length.  Unfortunately in .net 3.5 there is no CopyStream so you may have to write that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the HttpClient, you can install the download the REST starter Kit. and use the DLLs as external DLLs

http://forums.asp.net/t/1680252.aspx/1

Comment: My understanding is that while this would work with Winforms, I would be back to square one with Silverlight and WP7 which are two places we are looking at for this webservice.